# When notification bar is pulled,what is the state of activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to know the state of the activity when device notification bar pulled down.

I searched in many forums but didn't get proper answer.

I just want know the sequence of methods it will call.

Comment: I don't have a definitive source or answer, but I just did a test, and it appears that the Activity remains in the running state.